# How to specify an AbstractProcessor on the apt/javac command line?

Tags: java, ant, annotations, apt

I have a class that extends [`javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html), which I'd like to run over some `.java` files with `apt`.

How do I specify the class name on the `apt` command-line (or in an ant apt task)?  The command-line options I see, such as `-factory` expect an `AnnotationProcessorFactory`, not an `AbstractProcessor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use javac 1.6.0_20.

The relevant options for my compiler are

```
  -proc:{none,only}          Control whether annotation processing and/or compilation is done.
  -processor <class1>[,<class2>,<class3>...]Names of the annotation processors to run; bypasses default discovery process
  -processorpath <path>      Specify where to find annotation processors
  -d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
  -s <directory>             Specify where to place generated source files
```

I suspect you are using javac 1.5.*.  That JDK does not work with [AbstractProcessor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html) (which was introduced in 1.6).  The solution is to upgrade your JDK.